# Change android activity while app is in background?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity

My android app detects if the app is in the background (say the user pressed the home menu) using `ComponentCallbacks2`. Now, I want the app to change an activity **while it is currently in the background** without changing the users interface.

**My only question is:** How can I change the activity for when the user **in the background,** so that it pops up when he/she gets back to the app, rather than popping up as soon as I call `startActivity(Intent i)`.

Here are the steps that I want my app to execute:

1. User opens home menu in app (WORKS)
2. App detects that app is in background (WORKS)
3. **Using intents, open up another activity** without **disrupting** whatever app the user is on (DOESN'T WORK)

Right now, steps one and two are going fine. But, when I use an intent to change the activity, the activity pops open...disturbing the user. Basically, I want to load the activity, so that **as soon** as the user opens the app back up, it goes to the game over screen.

---

**My research on the topic, and what I've tried to resolve the issue on my own:**

I have done **lots** of research on this topic, but the other questions are about **running** processes in the background. For this, obviously, one would use a service. My question is laser focused on how I can change the activity for when the user **in the background,** so that it pops up when he/she gets back to the app. I have also tried to use the onContinue() method, but that gets called every time the user changes the activity, making it unreliable.

Thanks for the expert advice:

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to save your preferences in onStop (or when app is in background mode). Then use that info in OnCreate of SplashActivity to start Game-Over activity.

##

In your Activity where you detect background

```
 @Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();


  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("isGameOver", isGameOver);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
```

#########  Splash Activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean isGameOver = settings.getBoolean("isGameOver", false);
               if(isGameOver) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,GameOverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
 } else {
        // Start Main Activity
    }
            }
           }
        }; timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the point of the twenty second timer in the beginning though? I will mark you best answer and like your post once I get this, thanks so much!

Comment: When I tried doing the code (without the thread) my app just froze?

Comment: I have marked you best answer and liked. I had to change the answer though, because your method was freezing my app. Instead, I just used a boolean.

Comment: HI.. You can reduce the timer.  2000 -->  500. Splash activity shows a splash image whenever you start your app. You can observe this behaviour in many apps. However, you can change the time.

Comment: I have another question. How can I load my ads while the splash screen is displayed?

Comment: I think you can add that logic in Splash Activity. It is same as any other activity and has a layout. Your Splash screen can be ads too!

Comment: Thanks for the response. So there is a specific method for seeing when the add is loaded, but I have a very simple logic problem. You need to do `AdView.setListener` but, I am trying to load the add of the **next** activity, so I obviously don't have an AdView to add a listener to. So what should I do?